# How to declare varible to datepart function in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, group-by, datepart

Here i'm Trying to create stored procedure.. group by detepart..is it correct or wrong.??

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_NewvsOldOrders
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @NewCount INT
          , @NewRevenue INT
          , @NewDate DATETIME

    SELECT
         @NewDate = DATEPART(DAY, od.OrderDate)
       , @NewCount = COUNT(*)
       , @NewRevenue = SUM((CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), od.TotalAmount)))
    FROM orderdetails od
    INNER JOIN customer c
        ON od.customerid = c.customerid
    WHERE (CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), od.orderdate, 101))) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
        AND ((CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), od.orderdate, 101)))) = (CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), c.registereddate, 101)))))
        AND (od.TransactionId IS NOT NULL)
        AND (od.TransactionId <> '')
    GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, od.OrderDate)
           , od.OrderDate

END
```

Comment: On the `GROUP BY`, As you are `GROUP BY` both `DATEPART(DAY, od.OrderDate)` and `od.OrderDate` . As `DATEPART(DAY, od.OrderDate)` is day part of `od.OrderDate`, the `DATEPART(DAY, od.OrderDate)` is redundant

Comment: On the query, when you `GROUP BY` there might be more than one rows in the result. And only one of the row result will be assigning to variables.

Comment: `DATEPART()` returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the specified date. Why is the datatype of `@NewDate` `DATETIME`? It Should be `integer`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is how your stored procedures should be. As you didn't explain your requirement, i can really tell what you are trying to achieve

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_NewvsOldOrders
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
AS BEGIN

    -- not used
    --DECLARE @NewCount INT
    --      , @NewRevenue INT
    --      , @NewDate DATETIME

    SELECT
         NewDate    = DATEPART(DAY, od.OrderDate)
       , NewCount   = COUNT(*)
       , NewRevenue = SUM((CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), od.TotalAmount)))
    FROM orderdetails od
    INNER JOIN customer c
            ON od.customerid = c.customerid
    WHERE (od.orderdate >= StartDate) 
    AND   (od.orderdate <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate))
    AND   (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), od.orderdate, 101) 
         = CONVERT(DATETIME, c.registereddate, 101))
    AND   (od.TransactionId IS NOT NULL)
    AND   (od.TransactionId <> '')
    GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, od.OrderDate)
           --, od.OrderDate

END
```

Comment: I want new and old orders perday so in that query declared @NewCount   here i'm calucating registreddate=Orderdate is New customer

Comment: above mentioned query returns zero Values.. (0 row(s) affected)